# Rare RuntimeException when creating notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have a `GcmListenerService` that listens for GCM messages, then creates a notification:

```
  public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final String from, final Bundle data) {
        super.onMessageReceived(from, data);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String messager = data.getString("message");

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                // set title, message, style etc
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

All very standard. This works several thousands of times a day for thousands of users. 
I do though via Crashlytics receive a couple of the following crashes for the aforementioned line:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Can't create handler
>   inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

This happens almost exclusively on Android 6 (98%) and devices by a manufacturer called TCLCommunications.

Anyone already experienced something like that or has an idea what this is about?

It should be perfectly okay to create the notification from a background thread, right?

Comment: can you post your service code , though seems like you need to do this `run(){ Looper.prepare()....your code ...  Looper.loop()}`

Comment: @PavneetSingh I added the listener service code, nothing special going on. 
Do you think I have to force notificationManager.notify() to run on the main thread?

Comment: you can simply use this `NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);` otherwise i don't see any other suspecious thing here

Comment: I see the exact same problem with the TCL devices in Crashlytics.  I was going to force it to run on the UI thread, but decided to run a quick search first.  How did you end up address this, the UI thread?

Comment: @GaryBak Tbh I chose to ignore it :)